# Laravel how to get value from different tables at the controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I have a jQuery call in my page that takes data from a link I made in the controller like this:

```
public function api(Request $request , $project_id){

    return Program::where('project_id',$project_id)->get();
}
```

result :

```
[{"id":178,"project_id":37,"level_id":57,"zone_id":45,"ps":"2021-09-03","as":null,"pc":"2021-09-14","ac":null,"created_at":"2021-07-30T08:42:38.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-30T08:42:38.000000Z"},{"id":179,"project_id":37,"level_id":57,"zone_id":46,"ps":"2021-09-11","as":null,"pc":"2021-09-19","ac":null,"created_at":"2021-07-30T08:46:43.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-30T08:46:43.000000Z"},{"id":180,"project_id":37,"level_id":57,"zone_id":47,"ps":"2021-09-16","as":null,"pc":"2021-09-24","ac":null,"created_at":"2021-07-30T08:47:09.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-30T08:47:09.000000Z"},{"id":181,"project_id":37,"level_id":58,"zone_id":45,"ps":"2021-09-15","as":null,"pc":"2021-09-28","ac":null,"created_at":"2021-07-30T08:48:54.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-30T08:48:54.000000Z"},{"id":182,"project_id":37,"level_id":58,"zone_id":46,"ps":"2021-09-20","as":null,"pc":"2021-10-03","ac":null,"created_at":"2021-07-30T08:49:15.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-30T08:49:15.000000Z"},{"id":183,"project_id":37,"level_id":58,"zone_id":47,"ps":"2021-09-25","as":null,"pc":"2021-10-08","ac":null,"created_at":"2021-07-30T08:49:39.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-30T08:49:39.000000Z"}]
```

Now im trying to change the value of `zone_id` to come from a different table I have that that has `id = xx, name=xx`.
I usually do this by using `where()` but there is no page here so what would be the way to do this at the controller?

[image]

Comment: so, just to be sure, you want to pass `Zone`'s name as parameter to get related `Program`s? can't you use two query? like one fetching the `Zone` then gets the `Program`. i have no clue why javascript and jquery are relevant tags in this.

Comment: Is the program belongs to only one zone or connected many zone ?

Comment: @BagusTesa yes exactly what i need, it has to be solved in the backend

Comment: @VIKASKATARIYA 1 zone at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use WITH if ORM is setup in model, or you can use joins to get zone table along with program. it would look something like this.

```
return Program::where('project_id',$project_id)
    ->select('programs.*', 'zones.name')
    ->join('zones', 'programs.zone_id', '=', 'zones.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer that I found using Models:

```
$result = Program::where('project_id',$project_id)->get();
    foreach($result as &$row){
        $row->zone_name = Zones::where('id',$row->zone_id)->first()->name ?? '-';
    }
return $result;
```